# How to send a message from one scene to another using Scenic?

Tags: elixir

I've got a component named `ComponentX` with a function

`def handle_info(:do_x, state) do`

I try to call it from my main scene like so:

`send(Application.ComponentX, :do_x)`

I've also tried

`Process.send(Application.ComponentX, : [])`

But I end up with `** (ArgumentError) argument error` when trying both of those functions.

Comment: Does `ComponentX` implement `GenServer` behaviour? Please also post the whole stacktrace of the error you got back.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin  it has this at the top: use Scenic.Component, has_children: false

Comment: After further investigation I have found that Scenic uses make_ref to create keys for the pids in ets. I just don't know how to find the ref given a module name. Ideally I would like to avoid extra steps like pub/sub because the light weightness of my solution matters to me.

Comment: Mind to post the top of the `ComponentX` module? `ArgumentError` is a weird erlang way to tell VM could not find a process. You are to find a way to _name_ the process.

Comment: OK, I went to check the code; you are free to override [`child_spec/1`](https://github.com/boydm/scenic/blob/master/lib/scenic/scene.ex#L666-L674), or pass `name: Application.ComponentX` as an option when starting the component.

Comment: If I modify the `child_spec` like so 
```    %{
      id: __MODULE__,
      name: __MODULE__,
      start: {Scenic.Scene, :start_link, [__MODULE__, args, opts]},
      type: :worker,
      restart: :permanent,
      shutdown: 500
    }
```
How do I access it?

Comment: You are to modify it only changing `opts` in `start` argument: `%{..., start: {Scenic.Scene, :start_link, [__MODULE__, args, Keyword.put_new(opts, :name, __MODULE__)]}, ...}` and then you might call it as you did.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked like a charm @AlekseiMatiushkin. If you want to answer I would love to select your answer sa the correct one.

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/boydm/scenic/pull/201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I never used *Scenic* and I am not sure it’s the *proper, idiomatic* way to go.

---

`** (ArgumentError) argument error` as a result of calling `Kernel.send/2` is the [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) way to feedback “the target process is not found.”

```rb
iex(1)> defmodule M, do: (use GenServer) &&
...(1)>   (def handle_info(:do_x, state),
...(1)>      do: IO.inspect({:noreply, state}))

iex(2)> GenServer.start_link(M, name: M)
#⇒ {:ok, #PID<0.119.0>}
iex(3)> send M, :do_x  
#⇒ ** (ArgumentError) argument error
#      :erlang.send(M, :do_x)
```

That said, one needs to name the component to be able to send messages to it. `Scenic.Scene` does not allow to pass the name explicitly in a call to `use/2`, but it allows to override [`child_spec/1`](https://github.com/boydm/scenic/blob/master/lib/scenic/scene.ex#L666-L674).

That said, the following change in the overridden `child_spec/1` should do:

```
  def child_spec({args, opts}) when is_list(opts) do
    %{
      id: make_ref(),
-      start: {Scenic.Scene, :start_link, [__MODULE__, args, opts]},
+      start: {Scenic.Scene, :start_link,
+        [__MODULE__, args, Keyword.put_new(opts, :name, __MODULE__)]},
      type: :worker,
      restart: :permanent,
      shutdown: 500
    }
  end
```

Comment: **NB:** this is to become obsolete in the next version of `Scenic`. My [PR was merged](https://github.com/boydm/scenic/pull/201#event-3945659562) and soon we’ll have **`use Scenic.Component, name: ComponentX`** allowing **`send(ComponentX, :do_x)`** as in OP.